# How to keep several different photos files and choose one as background based on screen size?

Tags: angular, background-image

Starting from something like this in my .html file:

```
<mat-sidenav-content
    [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' + backgroundImageURL + ')',
        'background-size': backgroundSize, 'background-repeat': backgroundRepeat,
         'background-position': 'center center'}">
</mat-sidenav-content>
```

where `backgroundImageURL`, `backgroundSize` and `backgroundRepeat` are variables which I define in the something like "environment.ts" file,

how could I keep 3 different image files (eg *_-small*, *_-medium*, *_-large*), and apply one of them or the other depending on the screen size ?

Thanks.

Comment: Use `if... else` condition in `ts` file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can easily do that with for example a getter :

```
get backgroundImgUrl() {
   if (window.innerWidth > 1000) {
       return 'http://path-to-image.jpg';
   } else ...
}
```

But you should rather use srcset property : https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Apprendre/HTML/Comment/Ajouter_des_images_adaptatives_%C3%A0_une_page_web wich is html built-in.

Comment: I don't know how to use img srcset for a background, but the code sample did the trick. Thanks.

Comment: You can't use it as background, but you can put an absolute img in a relative container wich should do the work

Answer (score 0):

You should do it `ts` file.

Like

```
 let image = 'myImage';

 if (window.innerWidth < 420) {
     image += '-small';
 } else if (window.innerWidth < 768) {
     image += '-medium';
 } else {
     image += '-large';
 }

 this.backgroundImageURL  = image;
```